# Redirect subdir to root and root to subdir, avoiding infinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently have deployed the following .htaccess in my htdocs root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Map / to /foo.
RewriteRule ^$ /foo/ [L]

# Map /x to /foo/x unless there is a x in the web root.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1
```

This redirects example.com/foo/whatever to example.com/whatever, except if it matches other directories where other apps live (fox example example.com/admin/whatever, which should be kept that way). That part of the behaviour is desired. But now I have two urls for every page on foo, I have example.com/foo/whatever and example.com/whatever. I want to make a 301 redirect for all requests from /foo/x to /x, but if I add

```
# Redirect /foo/x to /x
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

to the .htaccess I obviously get a redirection infinite loop. How can I achieve what I want? Thanks in advance for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent a redirection loop, you can do a couple of things. If you are running an up-to-date Apache version you have access to the `[END]` flag. You can use this to stop rewriting completely when you internally rewrite, preventing the redirect to kick in.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1 [END]

# Redirect /foo/x to /x
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end)

If you don't have access to that flag you'll get an internal server error. In that case I would recommend to let the redirect rule only match on an external request.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1

# Redirect /foo/x to /x
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /foo/(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! ... well, for one case it did. On another case I'm facing, were foo/ is a CodeIgniter application and I have to redirect some requests to foo/index.php/whatever this doesn't work. [I made another question for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731052/redirect-root-to-codeigniter-app-in-subdir-avoiding-infinite-loop). Thanks again for your help!