# Redirect root to CodeIgniter app in subdir, avoiding infinite loop

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have deployed the following .htaccess in the directory of my CodeIgniter app:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and the following .htaccess in my htdocs root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Map / to /foo.
RewriteRule ^$ /foo/ [L]

# Map /x to /foo/x unless there is a x in the web root.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1
```

Where foo is the directory were my CodeIgniter app lives. This redirects example.com/foo/whatever to example.com/whatever, except if it matches other directories where other apps live (fox example example.com/admin/whatever, which should be kept that way). That part of the behaviour is desired. But now I have two urls for every page on foo, I have example.com/foo/whatever and example.com/whatever. I want to make a 301 redirect for all requests from /foo/x to /x, but if I add

```
# Redirect /foo/x to /x
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

to the .htaccess I obviously get a redirection infinite loop. [The solution described here for a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25729577/4020033) doesn't work, because it doesn't redirect to the index.php when needed. How can I achieve what I want? Thanks in advance for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this new rule in `/foo/.htaccess` to redirect `/foo/abc` to `/abc`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /foo/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```